# Need to list sql server tables that an application uses

Tags: sql-server

I need to be able to list all tables and views that an application accesses. Is there a way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "An application" is a bit vague. To list tables  you just need `SHOW TABLES FROM my_database`

Comment: This is a third party application, we would like to know which tables in the database it updates when the app run a specific process.

Comment: If this application uses a particular database, maybe you can check the cached execution plans so that you can find out the executed queries. https://www.sqlshack.com/searching-the-sql-server-query-plan-cache/

Comment: I think the answer to this will depend on which product you are using, MS SQL, Oracle, PostGres etc. Most databases have tools to allow you to trace what tables / views a user is accessing. Generally it's at the user level so you'll have to run the app using a known user which isn't active and hope that you capture all the SQL which the application can issue.